# Show a different image (bigger version) on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to load a different image (A bigger version) of existing one when mouse is hovered over that image. So I place all the images through AJAX call

```
<main class="container">     
    <ul class="gallery">            
    </ul>
</main>
```

```
success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                $(".gallery").append($(`<img src="${`images/square/${element.path}`}" 
                alt="${element.title}"id="${element.path}"city="${element.city}"
                taken="${element.taken}"/>`));
            });
        },
```

Now I want to load a bigger image (from local disk) of existing image when mouse is hovered and show that image over it (kind of zoom in, but not zoom in over the image but load a bigger image, and append the div to body) in the body.
I've tried many different versions of this

```
(".gallery").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).css("gray");
        $(this).append('<div id="preview"');
        // console.log($(this).attributes);
        // $(this).append($(`<img src="${`images/medium/"${$(this).attr('id')}"`}" 
        //                     alt="${$(this).attr('title')}"/>`
        //                 ));
        $(this).append('</div>')
        
    })
```

I am unable to access the attributes dynamically. `this.` attribute remains return undefined. Something seems off here. Can you please tell, how to go about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting attribute of `.gallery` which doesn't have any `id` or `alt` your `img` tag has that so use `.find()` to get that particular image where user hover and then get attributes using `.attr('yourattributename')`.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.gallery li', function() {
  var imgs = "<div id=preview><img src=images/medium/" + $(this).find('img').attr('id') + " alt=" + $(this).find('img').attr('alt') + "></div>";
  $(this).append(imgs)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="container">
  <ul class="gallery">
    <li><img src="images/square/${element.path}" alt="Soemehing" id="Soemehingdd" city="${element.city}" taken="${element.taken}" />
    </li>
    <li><img src="images/square/${element.path}" alt="Soemehing2" id="Soemehingdd2" city="${element.city}" taken="${element.taken}" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `$(.gallery .li)` does not seem to work. Not sure why `.li` is causing issue. Also the other thing (after removing `.li`) is that `this.id` always returns `id` of first image.

Comment: your appended code doesn't have li tag `$(".gallery").append($(<img` .But there should be `<li>` tag as well so appended data should look like `$(".gallery").append($("<li><img..></li>..` and li is not any class .

Comment: I tried with `$(".gallery").append($(`<li><img src="${`images/square/${element.path}`}" 
                alt="${element.title}"id="${element.path}"city="${element.city}"
                taken="${element.taken}"/></li>`)` as well. Additionally, it always appends `id` of first image even if we hover over another image.

Comment: So your selector should look like above answer which i have given . Make sure that html is same .Also , not `.li` just use `li`.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions. It doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure why we need to modify html in this case. My code is
```
$(".gallery li").mouseenter(function(){
        
        $(this).append('<div id="preview">');
        var imgs = `<img src=images/medium/${$(this).find('img').attr('id')} alt=${$(this).find('img').attr('alt')}/img>`;
        console.log(imgs);
        $(this).append(imgs);
        $(this).append('</div>');
    })
```

Comment: use `$(document).on('mouseenter', '.gallery li', function() {..` because here your `lis` are created dynamically .Do a simple `alert("hello")` inside your `$(".gallery li").mouseenter(function(){..` and see if this shows up .

Comment: Also I do not want to append to this, I want to append to body. When I do it, it says private fields are not allowed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222151/discussion-between-swati-and-kl-divergence).

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function instead of normal fucntion.

Arrow functions do not bind their own `this`, instead, they inherit the one from the parent scope, which is called "lexical scoping".

```
(".gallery").mouseenter(() => {
        $(this).css("gray");
        $(this).append('<div id="preview"');
        // console.log($(this).attributes);
        // $(this).append($(`<img src="${`images/medium/"${$(this).attr('id')}"`}" 
        //                     alt="${$(this).attr('title')}"/>`
        //                 ));
        $(this).append('</div>')
        
    })
```

Comment: I'm getting this error with your snippet 
`Uncaught TypeError: e.ownerDocument is null`

Comment: When I replace this entire function `(".gallery").mouseenter(function(){` with your snippet.

Comment: Are you getting some value in `this` now?